# Handwriting progressive drawing

Tags: javascript, complexity

[image: handwritting]

Implementation to progressively draw symbols, when provided with symbol implementations it supports any type of symbols, though for the review purpose just two hand written latin symbols are supported (q and x). It also supports font size, drawing line thickness and drawing speed configuration, pausing and notifying observers about drawing end.

Although I know is highly complex I’m unable to simple it. The hereby code review request is about identifying complex code snippets with resolutions to reduce complexity while preserving and when possible improving extensibility and maintainability. Also good to know are alternative implementations that exist, if any, maybe the available fonts already encapsulate information that can be used to progressive draw symbols, I don’t know.

The main components are a factory of line and ellipse outline pixels (called `adapter`), a factory of symbol outline (called `typeface`), a progressive painter (called `literate`) and an observer implementation (called `Diffuser`).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.board {
    height: 290px;
    width: 872px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}
.centered {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onclick="drawSomething()">
<div class="board centered"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var drawSomething = function() { wordsmith.font.size(65).pixels().tempo().adagio().word("qx"); };

var Diffuser = (function() {
    return { supply: function() {
        return (function() {
            var diffusees = [];
            var oneTimeDiffusees = [];
            
            var withdraw = function (value) {

                var once = function(values) {
                    var index = values.indexOf(value);
                    if ( index > -1 ) {
                        values.splice(index, 1);

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                };
                var remover = once;

                return { from: function(values) {
                                   return remover(values);
                         }
                       , entierly: function() {

                             remover = function(values) {
                                  var index = values.indexOf(value);
                                  if ( index == -1 ) { return false; }
                                  for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
                                      if ( values[i] === value ) {
                                          values.splice(i, 1);
                                      }
                                  }
                                  return true;
                              };

                              return this;
                       }
                     , once: function() { remover = once; return this; }
                     };
            };
            
            return {
                diffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    diffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , oneTimeDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , withdraw: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(diffusees);
                }
                , withdrawOneTimeDiffusee: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(oneTimeDiffusees);
                }
                , diffuse: function() {
                    var diffuseFunction = function() {
                        diffusees.forEach( (diffusee) => { (function() { diffusee(); })(); });
                    };
                    var oneTimeDiffuseFunction = function() {
                        for ( var i = 0; i < oneTimeDiffusees.length; i++ ) {
                            var diffusee = oneTimeDiffusees.pop();
                            if ( !(function() { return diffusee(); })() ) {
                                oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout( function() { 
                        
                        diffuseFunction();
                        oneTimeDiffuseFunction();
                        
                    }, 1);
                }
            };
        })();
    }};
})();

var vainer = (function() {
    return { supply: (purpose) => {
        var vainers = [() => { return false; }];
        if ( purpose ) { vainers.unshift(() => { vainers.shift(); return purpose(); }); }
        return { shift: function() { return vainers[0](); }
               , schedule: function(toSchedule) { 
                   vainers.unshift( () => { vainers.shift(); return toSchedule(); } );
                   return this;
               }
        };
    }};
})();

var wordsmith = (function(board) {
    
    var adapter = (function() {
        
        var thikness = 5;
        var dot = function() {
            var dotDiv = document.createElement("div");
            dotDiv.className = "dot";
            dotDiv.style.width = thikness + "px";
            dotDiv.style.height = thikness + "px";
            dotDiv.style.position = "absolute";
            return dotDiv;
        };
        
        var fields = (() => {
            var source = {};
            return { of: function(object) { source = object; return this; }
                   , to: { array: function() {
                                 var fields = [];
                                    for ( var field in source ) {
                                       fields.push(field);
                                    }
                                    return fields;
                    }}};
        })();
        
        var stepsNumberFor = (radius) => { return Math.floor( (2 * Math.PI * radius) / (thikness/2) ); };
        
        var linePixels = function(originX, originY, toX, toY) {

            var horizontal = ( originX > toX ) ? { start: toX, end: originX } : { start: originX, end: toX };
            var vertical = ( originY > toY ) ? { start: toY, end: originY } : { start: originY, end: toY };

            var xAxis = horizontal.end - horizontal.start;
            var yAxis = vertical.end - vertical.start;

            var numerator = (xAxis > yAxis) ? yAxis : xAxis;
            var denominator = (xAxis > yAxis) ? xAxis : yAxis;
            denominator = ( denominator == 0 ) ? 1 : denominator;
            var quotient = numerator / denominator;

            var xQuotient = ( xAxis > yAxis ) ? 1 : quotient;
            var yQuotient = ( xAxis > yAxis ) ? quotient : 1;

            var nextX = ( originX < toX ) ? (x) => { return x + xQuotient; } : (x) => { return x - xQuotient; };
            var nextY = ( originY < toY ) ? (y) => { return y + yQuotient; } : (y) => { return y - yQuotient; };

            var x = originX, untilX = toX;
            var y = originY, untilY = toY;

            var bound = ( x == untilX ) ? untilY : untilX;
            var variable = ( x == untilX ) ? (x, y) => { return y; } : (x, y) => { return x; };
            var drawed = 
                ( variable(x, y) >= bound ) ? (variable) => { return variable >= bound; } : (variable) => { return variable <= bound; };

            var pixels = [];
            while ( drawed( variable(x, y) ) ) {
                pixels.push( { x: x, y: y } );
                x = nextX(x);
                y = nextY(y);
            }
            return pixels;
        };

        var ellipsePixels = function(originX, originY, width, height, xAxisAngle, numberOfSteps, partOfEllipse, startingFrom) {
            var xAxisRadian = -xAxisAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
            var sinXAxisAngle = Math.sin(xAxisRadian);
            var cosXAxisAngle = Math.cos(xAxisRadian);

            var pixels = [];
            var index = (360 / numberOfSteps) * ( startingFrom || 0 );
            for ( var i = 0; i < Math.round(numberOfSteps * partOfEllipse); i++ ) {
                var ellipseRadian = index * (Math.PI / 180);
                index += (360 / numberOfSteps);
                var sin = Math.sin(ellipseRadian);
                var cos = Math.cos(ellipseRadian);
                var x = originX + (width * sin * cosXAxisAngle - height * cos * sinXAxisAngle);
                var y = originY - (width * sin * sinXAxisAngle + height * cos * cosXAxisAngle);
                x = Math.floor(x);
                y = Math.floor(y);

                pixels.push( { x: x, y: y } );
            }

            return pixels;
        };
        
        var ellipsePixelsAdapter = (ellipse, optionalCoordinates) => {
            var length = ( ellipse.height < ellipse.width ) ? ellipse.height : ellipse.width;
            var stepsNumberCoefficient = ( optionalCoordinates && optionalCoordinates.stepsNumberCoefficient ) ? optionalCoordinates.stepsNumberCoefficient : length;
            var numberOfSteps = stepsNumberFor(stepsNumberCoefficient);

            return  ellipsePixels( ellipse.originX, ellipse.originY, ellipse.width, ellipse.height, ellipse.rotated, numberOfSteps, ellipse.part, ellipse.partStartingFrom);
        };

        var linePixelsAdapter = (line) => {

            return linePixels(line.fromX, line.fromY, line.toX, line.toY);
        };
        
        var line = { fromX: 0, fromY: 0, toX: 0, toY: 0 };
        var ellipse = { width: 0, height: 0, originX: 0, originY: 0, part: 0, partStartingFrom: 0, rotated: 0 };
        var templates = [ { adapter: linePixelsAdapter, fields: fields.of(line).to.array() }
                        , { adapter: ellipsePixelsAdapter, fields: fields.of(ellipse).to.array() } ];
        
        return { of: (coordinatesObject) => {

            var coordinatesFields = fields.of(coordinatesObject).to.array();
            var emptyAdapter = () => {};
            var toReturn = emptyAdapter;
            for ( var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++ ) {
                var template = templates[i];
                var templateFields = template.fields;
                if ( coordinatesFields.length != templateFields.length ) {
                    continue;
                }
                var fieldContained = true;
                   for ( var coordinateField in coordinatesFields ) {
                       fieldContained = fieldContained && coordinateField in templateFields;
                   }
                   if ( fieldContained ) {
                       toReturn = template.adapter;
                       break;
                   }
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
        , line: { thikness: (lineThikness) => { 
                      thikness = lineThikness || thikness;
                      return { value: () => { return thkness; }
                             , dot: () => { return dot(); }};
    }}};})();
    
    var typeface = (function() {
        
        var absolute = (() => { return { of: (value) => { return value > 0 ? value : -value; }}; })();
        
        var last = (function() {
            return { of: (array) => {
                return { otherwise: (value) => { return ( array.length == 0 ) ? value : array[array.length - 1]; } };
            }};
        })();
        
        
        var array = (() => {
            return { of: (toArray) => {
                return [toArray].reduce( (accumulator, element) => accumulator.concat(element), []);
            } };
        })();
        
        var pixelsOf = (symbolBitSources, fromX, fromY) => {
            var sources = array.of(symbolBitSources);
            var originPixel = { x: fromX, y: fromY };
            var pixels = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++ ) {
                 var symbolBitSource = sources[i];
                 var lastPixel = last.of(pixels).otherwise(originPixel);
                 var symbolBit = (() => { return symbolBitSource(lastPixel.x, lastPixel.y); })();
                 var coordinates = symbolBit.description;
                 var symbolBitPixels = (() => { 
                     var optionalArguments = symbolBit.optionals || {};
                     return adapter.of(coordinates)(coordinates, optionalArguments);
                 })();
                 if ( (symbolBit.reverse || false) ) { symbolBitPixels.reverse(); }
                 pixels = pixels.concat(symbolBitPixels);
            }
            return pixels;
        };
        
        var xTypefaceSource = (function() {

            var spot = void(0);
            var xOffset = 0;
            var fontHeight = function() { return spot.fontSize(); };
            var ellipseWidth = function() { return fontHeight() * .25; };
            var line1Source = function(x, y) { var yAbsolute = absolute.of(y), nearBottomAbsolute = absolute.of(spot.near.bottom()), startFromNearBottom = absolute.of(yAbsolute  - nearBottomAbsolute) < 1.9, toX = ( startFromNearBottom ) ? x + fontHeight() * .3 : x + fontHeight() * .03, toY = spot.near.top(); return { description: { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
            var ellipse1Source = function(x, y) { xOffset = x; var height = fontHeight() * .5, width = ellipseWidth(), originX = x + width * .55, originY = spot.middle(), part = .75, partStartingFrom = -(fontHeight() * .16), rotated = 10; return { description: { height: height, width: width, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: rotated }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height } }; };
            var ellipse2Source = function(x, y) { var height = fontHeight() * .5, width = ellipseWidth(), originX = x + width * .9, originY = spot.middle(), part = .39, partStartingFrom = fontHeight() * .3, rotated = 10; return { description: { height: height, width: width, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: rotated }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height }, reverse: true }; };
            var ellipse3Source = function(x, y) { var height = fontHeight() * .5, width = ellipseWidth(), originX = x + width, originY = spot.middle(), part = .35, partStartingFrom = -(fontHeight() * .3), rotated = 10; return { description: { height: height, width: width, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: rotated }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height } }; };
            var ellipse4Source = function(x, y) { var height = fontHeight() * .5, width = ellipseWidth(), originX = x - width * .8, originY = spot.middle(), part = .7, partStartingFrom = fontHeight() * .52, rotated = 10; return { description: { height: height, width: width, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: rotated }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height }, reverse: true }; };
            var line2Source = function(x, y) { var fromX = x, fromY = y, toX = x + ellipseWidth() * .48, toY = spot.near.bottom(); return { description: { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
            var line3Source = function(x, y) { var fromX = x - ellipseWidth() * 2.3, fromY = spot.middle(), toX = fromX + ellipseWidth() + ellipseWidth() * .2, toY = fromY; return { description: { fromX: fromX, fromY: fromY, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };

            var typeface = () => {
                return { pixels: { from: function(x, y) {
                             var symbolBitSources = [ line1Source, ellipse1Source, ellipse2Source, ellipse3Source, ellipse4Source, line2Source, line3Source ];
                             return pixelsOf(symbolBitSources, x, y);
                         }}
                       , start: { pixel: function() { return { x: spot.x(), y: spot.near.top() }; }}
                       , connected: { from: { pixel: function() { return { x: xOffset + ellipseWidth() * 3.28, y: spot.near.bottom() };}}}
            };};
            
            return { symbol: "x"
                   , dimensioned: { by: (dimensions) => { spot = dimensions; return typeface(); }
        }};})();
        
        var qTypefaceSource = (function() {
            
            var spot = void(0);
            var xOffset = 0, yOffset = 0;
            var line1Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), yAbsolute = absolute.of(y), nearTopAbsolute = absolute.of(spot.near.top()), startFromNearTop = absolute.of( yAbsolute  - nearTopAbsolute ) < 1.1, toX = ( startFromNearTop ) ? x + fontHeight * .3 : x + fontHeight * .22, toY = ( startFromNearTop ) ? spot.top() : spot.middle(); return { description: { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
            var ellipse1Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), startFromMiddle = absolute.of( absolute.of(y) - absolute.of(spot.middle() ) ) < 1, width = fontHeight * .3, height = fontHeight * .5, part = startFromMiddle ? .4 : .17, partStartingFrom = startFromMiddle ? -(fontHeight * .5) : -(fontHeight * .033), originX = startFromMiddle ? x + width : x, originY = spot.middle(); return { description: { height: height, width: width, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: 10 }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: fontHeight * .7 } }; };
            var ellipse2Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), width = fontHeight * .3, height = fontHeight * .51, originX = x - width * .83, originY = spot.middle(), partStartingFrom = fontHeight * .43; return { description: { height: height, width: width, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: .8, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: 10 }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height }, reverse: true }; };
            var line2Source = function(x, y) { xOffset = x; yOffset = y; var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), toX = x + fontHeight * .1, toY = spot.top(); return { description : { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
            var line3Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), toX = x - fontHeight * .15, toY = spot.bottom() + fontHeight * .8; return { description : { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
               var ellipse3Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), circleRadius = fontHeight * .11, height = fontHeight * .5, originX = x - circleRadius, originY = y, part = .9, partStartingFrom = fontHeight * .3; return { description: { width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: 5 }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height } }; };
               var line4Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), toX = x + fontHeight * .1, toY = spot.bottom() + fontHeight * .85; return { description : { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
               var ellipse4Source = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), circleRadius = fontHeight * .11, originX = x + circleRadius, originY = y - circleRadius / 2, part = .3, partStartingFrom = fontHeight * .1; return { description: { width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: 5 }, reverse: true }; };
               var lineConnectionSource = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), toX = x + fontHeight * .07, toY = y + fontHeight * .1; return { description : { fromX: x, fromY: y, toX: toX, toY: toY } }; };
            var ellipseConnectionSource = function(x, y) { var fontHeight = spot.fontSize(), circleRadius = fontHeight * .13, height = fontHeight * .5, originX = x + circleRadius, originY = y - circleRadius / 2, part = 0.4, partStartingFrom = fontHeight * .3; return { description: { width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius, originX: originX, originY: originY, part: part, partStartingFrom: partStartingFrom, rotated: 5 }, optionals: { stepsNumberCoefficient: height}, reverse: true }; };
            var typeface = () => {
                
                return { pixels: { from: function(x, y) { 
                    var symbolBitSources = [ line1Source, ellipse1Source, ellipse2Source, line2Source, line3Source, ellipse3Source, line4Source, ellipse4Source ];
                    return pixelsOf( symbolBitSources, x, y );
                } }
                , start: { pixel: function() { return { x: spot.x(), y: spot.bottom() }; } }
                , connection: { pixels: function() { return pixelsOf([lineConnectionSource, ellipseConnectionSource], xOffset, yOffset); } }
                };
            };
                            
            return { symbol: "q"
                   , dimensioned: { by: (dimensions) => { spot = dimensions; return typeface(); }}
        };})();

        var emptyTypefaceSource = {
                symbol: void(0)
                , dimensioned: { by: (dimensions) => { 
                        return { pixels: { from: function(x, y) { return []; } }
                               , start: { pixel: function() { return { x: void(0), y: void(0) }; } }
                               , connected: { from: { pixel: function() { return { x: void(0), y: void(0) };}}}}; }
                }
        };

        var emptyTypeface = function() {
            return { pixels: { from: (x, y) => { return []; }}
                   , start: { pixel: function() { return { x: void(0), y: void(0) }; }}
                   , connected: { from: { pixel: function() { return { x: void(0), y: void(0) };}}}
        };};
        
        var typefaceSources = [xTypefaceSource, qTypefaceSource];
        return { source: { of: (symbol) => { 
                     var toReturn = emptyTypefaceSource;
                     for ( var i = 0; i < typefaceSources.length; i++ ) {
                         if ( typefaceSources[i].symbol == symbol ) {
                             toReturn = typefaceSources[i];
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                     return toReturn;
                 }}
                 , empty: () => { return emptyTypeface; }
    };})();

    var dimensions = (function() {

        return { from: function(fontSize, x, y) {

            var xOrigin = x || 0, yOrigin = y || 0, height = fontSize || 0;
            
            return { bottom: function() { return height + yOrigin; }
                   , middle: function() { return height * .5 + yOrigin; }
                   , near: { top: function() { return height * .13 + yOrigin; }
                           , bottom: function() { return height - height * .18 + yOrigin; } 
                           }
                   , x: function() { return xOrigin; }
                   , top: function() { return yOrigin; }
                   , fontSize: function() { return height; }
                   };
        }};
    })();
    
    var wordable = (symbol, index, length) => { return index < length
                                                       || "0123456789".indexOf(symbol) == -1
                                                       || " +-/%^±$#@&|\\{}[]()*!?.,;:'\"<>".indexOf(symbol) == -1};
    
    var fontSize = 135;
    var xOffset = 0, yOffset = 0;
    var lineThikness = 5;

    var trueReturner = () => { return true; };
    var literateMillis = 5;
    var literateShifter = vainer.supply( trueReturner );
    var literate = function(word) {

        if ( !literateShifter.shift() ) { 
            if ( !freezer.shift() ) { freezer.schedule( trueReturner ); }
            return;
        }

        var literable = Array.from(word);
        var metrics = dimensions.from(fontSize, xOffset, yOffset);
        var pixels = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < literable.length; i++ ) {
            var symbol = literable[i];
            var symbolTypeface = typeface.source.of(symbol).dimensioned.by(metrics);
            if ( i == 0 || literable[i - 1] == " " ) { 
                yOffset = symbolTypeface.start.pixel().y;
            }
            if ( symbolTypeface == typeface.empty() ) { xOffset += 100; continue; }

            var symbolPixels = symbolTypeface.pixels.from(xOffset, yOffset);
            if ( wordable(symbol) ) {
                var connectionPixels = (((symbolTypeface.connection || {}).pixels || ( () => { return []; } )))
                   symbolPixels = symbolPixels.concat(connectionPixels());
            }

               pixels = pixels.concat(symbolPixels);
               var lastPixelSource = () => { return symbolPixels[symbolPixels.length - 1]; };
               var lastPixel = (((symbolTypeface.connected || {}).from || {}).pixel || lastPixelSource)();
               xOffset = lastPixel.x;
               yOffset = lastPixel.y;
        }
        progressiveDrawing(pixels);
    };

    var freezer = vainer.supply();
    var literatedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
    var progressiveDrawing = function(pixels) {
        var draw = function() {
            if ( freezer.shift() ) { freezer.schedule( function() { progressiveDrawing(pixels); return true; } ); return; }
            if ( pixels.length == 0 ) {
                literateShifter.schedule( trueReturner );
                literatedDiffuser.diffuse();
                return;
            }
            var coordinate = pixels.shift();
            var pixel = adapter.line.thikness(lineThikness).dot();
            pixel.style.left = coordinate.x + "px";
            pixel.style.top = coordinate.y + "px";
            board.appendChild(pixel);

            setTimeout(() => { draw(); }, literateMillis);
        };
        draw();
    };
    
    var returnee = {
        word: function(literable) { literate(literable); return this; }
        , font: { weight: (lineThikness) => { thikness = lineThikness; }
                , size: function(size) { 
                      var context = returnee;
                      return { pixels: function() {
                          if ( size > 50 ) { fontSize = size } else { fontSize = 50; console.log("size is less than " + fontSize + "? it can be only higher"); }
                          return context;
                      }};
        }}
        , from: function() {
            var context = returnee;
            var xValue = 0, yValue = 0;
            var coordinates = { x: function(x) { xValue = x; return coordinates; }
                              , y: function(y) { yValue = y; return coordinates; }
                              , xy: function(x, y) { xValue = x; yValue = y; return coordinates; }
                              , pixels: function() { 
                                    if ( xValue != 0 ) { xOffset = xValue; xValue = 0; } 
                                    if ( yValue != 0 ) { yOffset = yValue; yValue = 0; }
                                    return context; 
                              }
                              , percent: function() { 
                                    if ( !board ) { console.log("percent of what?"); return context;}
                                    if ( xValue != 0) { var width = board.offsetWidth; xOffset = width * xValue / 100; xValue = 0; }
                                    if ( yValue != 0 ) { var height = board.offsetHeight; yOffset = height * yValue / 100; yValue = 0; }
                                    return context;
                              }};
            return coordinates;
        }
        , tempo: function() {
            var context = returnee;
            return { adagio: function() { literateMillis = 15; return context; }
                   , andante: function() { literateMillis = 10; return context; }
                   , allegro: function() { literateMillis = 5; return context; }
            };
        }
        , literatedDiffusedTo: function(diffusee) { literatedDiffuser.diffuseTo(diffusee); return this; }
        , literatedWithdraw: function(diffusee) { literatedDiffuser.withdraw(diffusee); return this; }
    };
    return returnee;
})(document.querySelector(".board"));
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest formatting this with [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/). Much of the formatting is non-standard, with some functions entirely on one line (~500 characters!).

Comment: The function `qTypefaceSource()` isn't source code. It is (partly) minified code, omitting whitespace that is important to humans. By presenting it in this way, the author is saying "here is some code, do not read it." Ok, we choose not to read it.

Comment: Natural handwriting consists of strokes. You're using parts of ellipsis for this which gives it a somewhat wooden look. For more natural curves have a look at _splines_ or _bézier curves_. Here's [an online example](https://jsfiddle.net/halfsoft/Gsz2a/). Another alternative would be actual pen input, which is great for getting a natural look and if you record it on [a digitizer](https://www.wacom.com) you get the velocity of the movement for free. Sorry, I haven't got much to say about your code, other than that it probably can use one more level of abstraction for the strokes.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? or did I miss something important?

Comment: @winner_joiner It seems the account of the user asking this question has been deleted. Try to avoid answering questions of users who do not respond to comments and have a low reputation. I intentionally left a remark at the end of my previous comment, to elicit a response from the user. If they had responded I would probably take a closer look, but I got nothing. My best guess is that the user got enough out of the comments/answers and wasn't interested in any interaction or keeping the account. Your answer is next level though.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for the clarification, I didn't realize. I just found the Question so interesting, that I went down the rabbit hole trying to come up with a solution. I will watch out for such account/questions in future. And thank you for the compliment. :)

Answer (score 3):

**This is not an improvement of your code** *(I now added some improvement tipps for you code, at the end)*, but **an alternative** option to solve your task, *as requested*. You would just have to draw all letters onces in a SVG formst *(maybe with a tool like Inkscape or so)*. Doing this minimize the code needed to display the hand drawn letters/symbols, improves the overall performance, the scalability and changing annding letters can be done easily in svg.
The whole animation is done with css, so no special calculations needed.

**Mini demo / proof of concept:**
*(I just created the two letters you are showcasing)*

```js
// --> HTML Setup
let lettersSvg = document.querySelector('#svg');
let boardSvg = document.querySelector('#board');
let letters = [].reduce.call(lettersSvg.querySelectorAll('g'), (p,c) => {
  p[c.id] = c;
  return p;
},{});

// --> Output definition & Setup
let lettersToWrite = 'qxxxxq'.split('');
let fontSize = 6;
let nextLetterOffset = fontSize * 5; // I just eye-balled it, for the demo

let setFontSizeTransform = boardSvg.createSVGTransform();
setFontSizeTransform.setScale(fontSize, fontSize);

// -> to keep the animation order ...
let promise = Promise.resolve();

for(let idx = 0 ; idx < lettersToWrite.length; idx++){
  let letter = lettersToWrite[idx];
  let svgLetter = letters[letter].cloneNode(true);

  // add next Letter offset & fontsize
  let letterOffsetTranform = boardSvg.createSVGTransform();
  letterOffsetTranform.setTranslate( idx * nextLetterOffset, 0);
  
  svgLetter.transform.baseVal.appendItem(letterOffsetTranform);
  svgLetter.transform.baseVal.appendItem(setFontSizeTransform);
  
  let paths = [...svgLetter.querySelectorAll('path')];

  // Calc whole path length in group to calculate animation-duration  
  let wholeLength = paths.reduce( (p,c) => p +c.getTotalLength(), 0);
  
  // Set properties, varibales & event to control the animation
  for(let path of paths){
    let length = path.getTotalLength();
    promise = promise.then(() => {
        return new Promise( (resolve) => {
          path.style.setProperty('animation-name', 'drawPath');   
          path.addEventListener("animationend", _ => resolve());
          path.style.setProperty('--color',  'black');
          path.style.setProperty('--speed', `${ length/ wholeLength }s`);
          path.style.setProperty('--line-length', length);          
        });
    });
  }
  boardSvg.append(svgLetter);
}
```

```css
path {
   --speed: 1s;
   
   stroke-width: .6;  
   stroke: var(--color);
   stroke-dasharray: var(--line-length);
   stroke-dashoffset: var(--line-length);
   animation-duration: var(--speed); 
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes drawPath {
   1% { stroke-dashoffset: var(--line-length); }
   100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="letters" style="display:none">
<svg version="1.1" id="svg" >
    <g id="q" >
     <path d="M 3.6944839,13.099561 4.9000712,9.4225184" style="fill:none;" class="q-0" />
     <path style="fill:none" d="M 4.8893164,9.4426596 C 5.1253463,7.9794554 6.0241921,7.0452432 7.1342686,6.3766276 8.2346859,5.9709225 8.9595307,6.5417057 9.6660024,7.1602592 9.039501,6.5795651 8.3065427,6.1319422 7.0438496,6.3464877 6.1024082,7.1911898 5.3175449,8.2421818 4.9943509,9.7824128 5.0665119,11.14691 4.9488829,11.492884 5.6272843,12.253867 6.1618822,12.853541 6.7853738,13.541385 7.767202,12.91694 8.9803483,12.145377 9.3549455,8.4166598 9.9975387,6.1656497 c 0,0 -2.6447489,11.9715813 -4.3702542,16.8480843 -0.1206453,0.340961 -0.6368156,0.686814 -1.0850287,2e-6 -0.1672066,-0.550512 -0.00356,-1.036833 0.3918158,-1.265867 0.9103032,0.06202 1.8077107,1.098645 2.3508955,0.391816" id="q-1" />
  </g>
  <g id="x" >
    <path d="m 3.6793201,13.119066 c 0,0 0.5456098,-2.347718 1.2785978,-2.933926" style="fill:none;" id="x-0" />
    <path style="fill:none;" d="m 4.9659824,10.194534 c 0.2199362,-0.175894 0.7927523,-0.2168078 1.0388606,-0.07991 0.7302298,0.406195 0.6501699,0.936893 0.6931123,1.47993 0.027895,0.352759 -0.095843,0.692424 -0.2935506,1.020186 -0.4032886,0.668575 -0.9931964,0.445222 -0.9931964,0.445222" id="x-1" />
    <path style="fill:none;" d="m 8.3907978,13.117043 c 0,0 -0.7117987,-0.0147 -0.8219555,-0.05708 -0.5443339,-0.209409 -0.8473894,-0.501651 -0.8676199,-1.084525 -0.00773,-0.222618 -0.068467,-0.504717 0.022831,-0.730627 0.2079378,-0.514526 0.3073444,-0.82737 0.7991237,-1.084525 0.156433,-0.0818 0.673547,-0.0685 0.673547,-0.0685" id="x-2" />
    <path style="fill:none;" d="m 5.7075876,11.758533 c 0.706607,-0.03621 1.1397448,-0.02292 2.1397448,-0.02292" id="x-3" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
<svg id="board"></svg>
```

**That said, here some tipps to improve your code:**

Well I went through your code and somethings, that I think could/should be improved are:

- use `let` instead of `var`, this should help with scoping issues
- use normal `functions` rather than [function expressions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)
- Remove all the **unneeded** [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
  like for example *(there are many cases of this)*:

**Instead of:**

```
  var absolute = (() => { 
      return { of: (value) => { return value > 0 ? value : -value; } };
  })();
```

**Use:**

```
  var absolute =  { of: (value) => { return value > 0 ? value : -value; } };
```

- Use Standard functions instead of coding it yourself:

**Instead of:**

```
  var absolute = (() => { 
      return { of: (value) => { return value > 0 ? value : -value; } };
  })();
  ...
  absolute.of(y)
```

**Use:**

```
  // just use
  Math.abs(y)
```

- Don't nest function in functions *(or loop or so)*, if this is not really needed

**Instead of:**

```
var pixelsOf = (symbolBitSources, fromX, fromY) => {
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        ...
        var symbolBitPixels = (() => {
            var optionalArguments = symbolBit.optionals || {};
            return adapter.of(coordinates)(coordinates, optionalArguments);
        })();
        if ((symbolBit.reverse || false)) { symbolBitPixels.reverse(); }
        ...

    }
    ...
};
```

**Use:**

```
var symbolBitPixels = (coordinates, symbolBit) => {
    var optionalArguments = symbolBit.optionals || {};
    return adapter.of(coordinates)(coordinates, optionalArguments);
};

var pixelsOf = (symbolBitSources, fromX, fromY) => {
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        ...
        var coordinates = symbolBit.description;
        ...
        if ((symbolBit.reverse || false)) { symbolBitPixels(coordinates, symbolBit).reverse(); }
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

- Remove *unneeded* Checkes / functions like:

**Instead of:**

```
 if ((symbolBit.reverse || false))
```

**Use:**

```
if (symbolBit.reverse)
```

**OR**

```
var array = (() => {
    return {
        of: (toArray) => {
            return [toArray].reduce((accumulator, element) => accumulator.concat(element), []);
        }
    };
})();
```

It is used once on an Array, so it returns a new Array, that has the same values, so this function only increases the performance.

- for the letters, I would just use the parameters needed for the functions (ellipse, line) in an array and pass them, don't pass functions, since this duplicates the code needlessly.

> personally I would remove, all the unneeded Chaining steps, that don't add functionality, or could merged. like by the `fields` function/object. this could be optimizes/shortened to:

```
let fields = {
    source: {},
    of: function (passedObject) { this.source = passedObject; return this; },
    toArray: function () {
        return Objects.keys(this.source);
    }
};
```

***Just to name a few things.***